# Sed error in bash shell script

Tags: bash, sed

I have this code:

```
sed -i -s "1i${var}" $file
```

I need to copy all the content of the variable `var` into the top of the file without deleting the content of the file. When `var` has one line, the command works well, but when `var` has multiple lines I get this error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, character 28:  extra characters after command
```

I need to use sed.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

if $var has line breaks, sed will give error
you need append '\' after each line if you want to insert multiple lines

```
$ echo abc | sed -e '1iinsert 1st line
2nd line'
sed: -e expression #1, char 21: extra characters after command
$ echo abc | sed -e '1iinsert 1st line\
2nd line'
insert 1st line
2nd line
abc
```

`man sed` search for insert

> ```
>    i \
>
>    text   Insert text, which has each embedded newline preceded by a back-
>           slash.
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You have to take into account the fact that `sed` does not expand the `${var}` part.
Bash does.  Sed receives a string where `${var}` has already  been replaced with the actual content of `$var`.
You need to make sure such substitution will result in a valid `sed` command.